# ansible `fetch` requiring a `changed_when: false`?

Tags: ansible

When I run following `ansible` (v2.8.4) task I get

```
`changed: [1.2.3.4]`
```

whereas I expect

`ok: [1.2.3.4]`

since `fetch` is (I thought) only changing the **local** side.

```
- name: Foo
  fetch:
    dest: config/
    flat: true
    src: /etc/foo/bar.tar.gz
```

I can, of course, avoid this by using  `changed_when: false` but that seems a bit weird?

Quoting the docs:

> It is used for fetching files from remote machines and storing them
>   locally in a file tree, organized by hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible lets you describe predictable states. In your specific case, you are using the [`fetch` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html) (but using [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) would be identical delta the transfer direction) and describing the following:

> fileX (aka dest) on serverA must exist and have the same content as fileY (aka src) on serverB

There are only 2 reasons that can explain your result between 2 consecutive plays:

1. the destination file was modified or removed (e.g. after you were done decompressing it)
2. the source file was modified.

Just as a proof, a test playbook `fetch.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: test fetch idempotency
      fetch:
        dest: /tmp/
        flat: true
        src: "{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/test.txt"
```

First run:

```
$ # Create the fetched file
$ echo "test line" > $HOME/test.txt
$ # Run playbook
$ ansible-playbook fetch.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test fetch idempotency] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Second run

```
$ ansible-playbook fetch.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test fetch idempotency] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see above, nothing was changed. But if you change the source or dest:

```
$ # Run either of the following commands
$ #
$ # Modify the source
$ echo "change file on host" >> $HOME/test.txt
$ # or modify the destination
$ echo "change file on controler" >> /tmp/test.txt
$ # or delete the destination
$ rm /tmp/test.txt
$ # and run playbook again
$ ansible-playbook fetch.yml

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test fetch idempotency] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I expected that changed was referring to the *remote machine, from which we are fetching files*. It seems a bit weird to me that the client (local side) machine state affects the play state? I suspect yes the tar.gz was removed on client side (But i need to check) later in the playbook. Seems I’ve misunderstood *changed* and it depends on changes on **either or both sides** ?

Comment: Ansible is about describing predictable states. The `fetch` and `copy` modules do the same thing. Only the transfer direction changes. You describe a state: `fileX (aka dest) on hostA must exist and have the same content as fileY (aka src) on hostB`. If either file changes after your first run, you have to transfer again to get to the described state, which results in the module reporting `changed`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense now. I do think that the logs a little corner-intuitive as they have *ok* or *changed* beside the ipaddress of the machine my ansible-client is pointing at, ie where we are fetching the file from, even though it’s the dst, ie where I’m running ansible-client that is **actually changing**.  But I get now that is just how it is !

Comment: I think the last comment you wrote would be good to insert at the end of your answer ... as I understand comments can be somewhat ephemeral in stackoverflow world